# How to append a statement effectively in already existing file through java

Tags: java, file, read-write

I want to append below statement to an already existing file.

```
setOneMoreWorkingLineWithServiceID("01014051484", "84", "PSTN Single Line", "N", "", "A line in e2e", "", "NTE", "", "", "Standard", "");
```

#### Original file

```
package config;

public class ABC extends LineAvailabilityNew
{

    public ABC(Message msg) throws MessageHandlerExcection
    {
        super(msg);
    }

    public void doMessageDataOverrides() throws MessageHandlerExcection
    {
        super.doMessageDataOverrides();
        setWorkingLineQty("21");
        setStoppedLineQty("10");
        setworkingLineExchangeGroupCode("GOL");
        setWorkingLineWithServiceID("01014013024", "24", "MPF", "N", "N", "A line in e2e", "", "NTE", "GOL", "", "Standard", "");
        setOneMoreWorkingLineWithServiceID("01014013025", "25", "MPF", "N", "N", "A line in e2e", "", "NTE", "GOL", "", "Standard", "");
        setOneMoreWorkingLineWithServiceID("01014013026", "26", "MPF", "N", "N", "A line in e2e", "", "NTE", "GOL", "", "Standard", "");
        setOneMoreStoppedLineWithServiceID("01014013015", "15", "PSTN Single Line", "N", "N", "", "NTE", "GOL", "", "Standard", "");

    }
}
```

#### Criteria:

1. The content of original file is not always the same. i.e. the calls inside `doMessageDataOverrides()` may vary.
2. If `setOneMoreWorkingLineWithServiceID()` already exists then I need to add the new stated line after the last occurrence of `setOneMoreWorkingLineWithServiceID()`.
3. If `setOneMoreWorkingLineWithServiceID()` does not exist already then I need to add the statement after `setworkingLineExchangeGroupCode()/setStoppedLineQty()`

How do I add the statement to the existing file along with satisfying the given criteria?

Comment: and what is the Problem?

Comment: Changing on source code could be a very complex problem. You propably needs a Java parser. I think you can do it better with a correct algorithm and data structure.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need some subclasses for your class and override the doMessageDataOverrides() method. You cannot change the classes on the fly, they are not dough, but you can use the right ABC subclass.

Answer (score 0):

I see multiple solutions to this problem

**Simple Java Streams**:

Use a stream and look for `doMessageDataOverrides()`, after that look for `setOneMoreStoppedLineWithServiceID(` and add your needed line in the correct position.

**Search and Replace**

You could use some magic search and replace regexp to find the correct lines and edit your files

**Java Parser**

Use a Java parser like JDT, create an AST, walk over the AST and insert the needed nodes. I think this is the most robust one.